# Validación de datos con Laravel 5.4 (no se visualiza los errores en mi formulario)

Tags: laravel-5, validación

Estoy usando laravel 5.4.

Quiero validar los datos de mi formulario para lo cual use el método validate de laravel. me está validando todo bien. Pero no puedo visualizar esos errores en mi formulario, vi unos tutoriales donde se utiliza la variable $errors, la estoy usando pero es como si estuviera vacia, sin embargo por consola tengo un request que me trae errors y ahi si me refleja los errores de valicacion (adjunto imagen).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy utilizando el siguiente código para visualizar en mi formulario

```
@if(true)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <p>
            <strong>
                Surgieron los siguientes errores
            </strong>
        </p>
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{$error}}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

Pero no me aparece nada.

Comment: ¿Asumo que es una solicitud ajax?

Comment: Estoy usando VueJS y Axios por ende si.

Comment: Edita la pregunta y agrega por favor el código relacionado con el rendering de dicha sección.

Comment: Gracias ya encontré la solución.

Comment: entonces borra la pregunta por favor